# Building simple rails app fails, rake (and others) not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I've pulled the minimal Rails app on https://github.com/hahmed/cool_app_minimal.git and added one minimal view (added a controller and an index view with `root :to => 'main#index'` in routes.rb). (Also changed the project name to 'minirails'.) This runs perfectly fine on my machine.
I have a Dockerfile, which is my standard Dockerfile (see below), and I can't get it to build. It fails at `RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile` with the bizarre error

```
 > [10/11] RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile:                                                     
#14 0.596 bundler: failed to load command: rake (/minirails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rake)         
#14 0.597 Gem::Exception: can't find executable rake for gem rake. rake is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
#14 0.597   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
#14 0.597   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
#14 0.597   /minirails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

If I comment out this command the image builds successfully, but I can't start it, here the error message is

```
Marions-MacBook-Pro-2:minirails marion$ docker run --name minirails minirails
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/minirails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rake)
Gem::Exception: can't find executable rake for gem rake. rake is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /minirails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile (I changed it a bit from the one included in cool_app_minimal):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
end
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.6-bullseye
LABEL maintainer="Me"

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENV PATH=/root/.yarn/bin:$PATH RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=c1f89d98........d47bc66fdcd417
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get update && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7 && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates && \
    sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger bullseye main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list' && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger curl certbot python3-certbot-nginx && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list &&\
    apt-get install -y yarn nano cron

RUN apt-get -y install tzdata && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /minirails/

WORKDIR minirails

COPY ./ /minirails

RUN mkdir /minirails/vendor
RUN bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1 
RUN bundle config set deployment 'true'
RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle install

RUN echo "Rails.application.config.app_version = '$(date +%d.%m.%Y)'" > ./config/initializers/version.rb

#RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
sleep 10 && bundle exec rake db:migrate
bin/rails s
```

If I change the file docker-entrypoint.sh to

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
sleep 10 && bundle exec rake db:migrate
passenger start --port 3000
```

the container starts up, but passenger can't spawn a process, giving me the error

```
=============== Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /minirails/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /minirails/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/
...
===============================================================================
[ N 2023-06-15 11:30:50.6347 58/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 97 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- rack (LoadError)
...
[ E 2023-06-15 11:30:51.6135 58/Tj age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /minirails: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- rack (LoadError)
```

This sounds as if nothing Rails-related was installed properly. What is wrong, how can I debug it?

Comment: Are you sure the ruby version off your app isn't mismatch with the system's ?

Comment: @plombix Good point. Unfortunately, no. I checked. I mean, the Ruby versions are really the same.

Comment: There is may a pb with the minirails ENV setup . You install it "without dev / text"
Have you try to set specificly your env in your server start ? 
Either  remove "without test / dev " in minirails 's install , OR add "RAILS_ENV=production" in your server's start command.
It look like you have a pb of path so if it's not the ruby => gem link it may be the env => gem .

Comment: @plombix OMG. I had a dim suspicion that it was some really dumb thing. I haven't tested yet but I'm sure you've hit it. Usually I have a docker-compose file in which I define the RAILS_ENV. Here I start the container with docker run because it's only one container. In this case RAILS_ENV doesn't get set of course. So Rails doesn't know where to look for the Gems. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help , please validate the answer , i 'll clean the comments .

Comment: i deleted the answer , after your edits .

Comment: Thanks. (In case anyone else reads this: Unfortunately setting the RAILS_ENV properly didn't help.) What is particularly baffling for me is that I've successfully dockerized about five projects.... all using this Dockerfile. The only difference between those projects and this one is that I "inherited" all the other projects from other developers, and this one is the first project I'm creating from scratch myself. But how on earth can this make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dockerfile is missing the command

```
ENV RAILS_ENV production
```

before executing bundle install. It seems that the command in line 7 of my Dockerfile was not enough (or incorrect). The only changes I made in the end were

```
...
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /minirails/

RUN mkdir /minirails/vendor
WORKDIR minirails

COPY ./ /minirails

ENV RAILS_ENV production
RUN bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1 
RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle install
...
```

... and now it works.